# Getting [object HTMLImageElement] instead of the image

Tags: javascript, html

I am revamping my website and I want a minecraft server status widget on there, I found a really good one from MCAPI.net. They have a demo HTML + JS code that I used and modified to my own use. The code writes everything as text with up for online and down for offline, but instead of boring old text I want an image, green for up, red for down. I Googled how to get `innerHTML` to show an image, after **A LOT..** of finecking around I didn't get any error messages but I got [object HTMLImageElement] instead.. And now I'm stuck..

Full code (It's contained in it's own HTML file, I'll be copy/pasting it into it's own JS when it goes on the main site):

```html
<script src="https://mcapi.us/scripts/minecraft.js"></script>
<div class="server-status">
<span class="server-online"></span>Players: <span class="players-online"></span>/<span class="players-max"></span>
</div>
<script>
  MinecraftAPI.getServerStatus('porotrails.com', {
  },
  
  function (err, status) {
 var up = new Image();
 var down = new Image();
 up.src = "images/up.png";
 down.src = "images/down.png";
    if (err) {
      return document.querySelector('.server-status').innerHTML = 'Error';
    }
 
    document.querySelector('.server-online').innerHTML = status.online ? up : down;
 document.querySelector('.players-online').innerHTML = status.players.now;
 document.querySelector('.players-max').innerHTML = status.players.max;
  });
</script>
```

I'm thinking for some reason this line is failing to do it's job.

```
document.querySelector('.server-online').innerHTML = status.online ? up : down;
```

TL;DR: I need to show an image instead of `[object HTMLImageElement]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The issue is that when using `.innerHTML()`, you should provide a
>   `string` value to become the content of the element in question, but
>   you are using the W3C DOM Standard approach to creating a new element
>   node and when you pass that object to the `innerHTML()` method, the
>   JavaScript run-time, converts it into a string and the result is the
>   description of that   object  (Object HTMLImageElement).

You can solve your problem in one of two ways...

1. Don't use `.innerHTML()` and use `.appendChild()` instead. `.appendChild()` expects an object reference to be passed into it and since you have created explicit object instances (`up` and `down`), you can pass those.
2. Use `.innerHTML()` and create a string value. When doing this, you make the HTML yourself and pass it as a string.

Below, I have adjusted your code to use approach #2, but added the commented code for solution 1 as well.

```html
<script src="https://mcapi.us/scripts/minecraft.js"></script>
<div class="server-status">
<span class="server-online"></span>Players: <span class="players-online"></span>/<span class="players-max"></span>
</div>
<script>
  MinecraftAPI.getServerStatus('porotrails.com', {
  },
  
  function (err, status) {
    // Solution 1: Pass a string to innerHTML
 var up = "<img src='images/up.png'>";
 var down = "<img src='images/down.png'>";
    
    // Solution 2: Use DOM to create image element nodes and insert using DOM
    //var up = new Image();
    //var down = new Image();
    //up.src = 'images/up.png';
    //down.src = 'images/down.png';

    if (err) {
      return document.querySelector('.server-status').innerHTML = 'Error';
    }
 
    // Solution 1:
    document.querySelector('.server-online').innerHTML = status.online ? up : down;
    
    // Solution 2:
    //document.querySelector('.server-online').appendChild(status.online ? up : down);
    
    
 document.querySelector('.players-online').innerHTML = status.players.now;
 document.querySelector('.players-max').innerHTML = status.players.max;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`up` and `down` are `HTMLImageElement` objects, not HTML strings. Assigning them to `innerHTML` casts them to strings, resulting in `[object HTMLImageElement]` from this line:

```
document.querySelector('.server-online').innerHTML = status.online ? up : down;
```

Try something like this instead:

```
var serverOnline = document.querySelector('.server-online');
// Remove any children (unnecessary if always empty before hand).
serverOnline.innerHTML = '';
// Append the image element.
serverOnline.appendChild(status.online ? up : down);
```

Alternately, you could make `up` and `down` HTML strings.

```
var up = '<img src="images/up.png" />';
var down = '<img src="images/down.png" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you change `innerHTML`, it expects a string, but `up` and `down` are image objects. Instead of changing the `innerHTML`, you can use `appendChild` to add the image to an element.

Replace

```
document.querySelector('.server-online').innerHTML = status.online ? up : down;
```

with

```
var container = document.querySelector('.server-online');
container.innerHTML = "";
container.appendChild(status.online ? up : down);
```

Before appending the image, the contents of the container must be cleared so that the old images are removed when the status changes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try the literal style, like this:

```
var up = "<img src='images/up.png' />";
var down = "<img src='images/down.png' />";
```

or using another way to get the information of that node

```
document.querySelector('.server-online').innerHTML = status.online ? up.outerHTML : down.outerHTML;
```